# Communication between manager class and object class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I'm facing a designissue. I'm using DDS (Data Distribution Service) protocol to communicate between application.
In my DDS Library I have 3 classes:
- DDSWriter to write messages to other applications
- DDSReader to read messages from other applications
- DDSManager to instantiate the two others, manage them and be the entry point for the application

DDSManager have an objet which refer to DDSWriter and another which refer to DDSReader.
DDSReader have a thread to read continually the data that we receive but no objet we refer to DDSManager.

How can I send data from DDSReader to DDSManager in this case ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: look like homework to me. please show us what have you tried.

Comment: Do you think the `DDSReader` must keep its manager's reference (or pointer, or something else in the context)?

Comment: I try nothing I'm just thinking about this problems before implement my code.
I think DDSReader do not have manager's reference. Manager have reference to DDSReader because it create this objet but to be clean I wish that DDSReader don't have reference to DDSManager but I need to send data from DDSReader to DDSManager.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with an other software architect that what I need can't be implement.
But I can implement the design pattern [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which permits to abstract DDSManager instance for DDSReader object.

Thanks for your help and I hope this can be help other person.